# SQL Navigator prompts every time I'm closing it

Tags: sql, oracle, configuration

I'm using SQL Navigator that is connected to the Oracle server of our company.

[alt text http://i34.tinypic.com/3583wxf.jpg](http://i34.tinypic.com/3583wxf.jpg)

Whenever I run a query or two and exit the program, it prompts the following confirmation window:

[image]

I don't think that I have pending transactions. To close the program, I have to click on Yes or No and this is annoying. I also tried that: I opened the program and closed it without running any queries. This way it didn't prompt.

How can I suppress this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling any functions in your queries? Maybe they have sideeffects (inserting / updating data).

Comment: I have no user rights to insert or update data. I just use some views to fetch data.

Comment: I would recommend you get in touch with your DBA and send them some example queries, so he can reproduce. If he can't, try another SQL Client like SQLDeveloper, as this might be a bug in SQL Navigator.